# C# Get Label Address For Lookup Table?

Tags: c#, .net, optimization

I'm trying to optimize an algorithm I've been working on in C#. I have a while loop that will continue as long as a couple of variables are not 0. I was hoping to potentially replace this with some binary arithmetic & lookup table to avoid conditional branching.

```
while(a != 0 && b != 0 ) {
   // DO WORK
}
```

I was hoping I might be able to do something like this:

```
var lookup_table = [next_iteration, done];
next_iteration:
    // DO WORK
    goto lookup_table[<< a&b? 0 : 1 >>];
done:
```

Replacing the `<< a&b? 0 : 1 >>` with binary arithmetic. Probably folding all the bits to the 1s place in a & b, and then masking out other bits in the final AND operation. Perhaps there's a better technique.

Of course, this level of optimization may just be beyond the capabilities of C#/Managed Languages without dropping into IL (which could be a valid solution). In which case I can drop down to **C/C++**. I'm curious to see if I can't get it to work in C# though.

Comment: C and C++ compilers are pretty smart these days. If you wrote that in one of those languages, would it actually run faster than the compiler optimized while loop?

Comment: @AluanHaddad I'm not sure offhand if C/C++ compilers would or would not handle the above optimization. I'd have disassemble it and take a look and/or benchmark it - which I'm presently working on in .NET.